# Dynamically created TextBox Name and Position Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, textbox

**I have completed the questions i have asked, Thanks to everyone who answered.**

At the moment in my application I have a two buttons which can create my TextBoxs and put them into the position I want them to go.

C# Code:

```
private void btnAddTitle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        TextBox x = new TextBox();
        x.Name = "new_textbox";
        x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        x.Height = 25;
        x.Width = 200;
        x.AcceptsReturn = true;
        x.Margin = new Thickness(10, 15, 950, 0);
        spStandard.Children.Add(x);
 }

 private void btnQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        TextBox x = new TextBox();
        x.Name = "new_textbox";
        x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        x.Height = 25;
        x.Width = 200;
        x.AcceptsReturn = true;
        x.Margin = new Thickness(10, 15, 850, 0);
        spStandard.Children.Add(x);
 }
```

XAML Code:

```
<Button x:Name="btnAddTitle" Content="Add Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="919,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Height="24" Background="{x:Null}" Click="btnAddTitle_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="btnQuestion" Content="Add Question" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1080,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Height="24" Click="btnQuestion_Click"/>

<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="22,82,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1200"/>
<Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="34,132,33,72">
        <StackPanel x:Name="spStandard" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-2,-2,-2" Width="1181"/>
</Border>
```

Picture of the code in action:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/REWTe.png

(The Title TextBoxs are closer to the border and the question TextBoxs have a gap)

****ANSWERED** My first question is:** When I click the button and it Dynamically creates the different TextBoxs. How can I give them different Names/ID's so I can get the information out of that TextBox later on when I need it?

**My last question is:** When I edit the width of the TextBox (`x.Width = 200;`) so that the user can add a bigger question, the TextBox losses position and also the margin.

Picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKhUH.png

(It seems to lose the margin and also cut of the edge of the TextBox when I make bigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question you can generate text box name dynamically.

```
int y = 0;

        private void btnAddTitle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox x = new TextBox();
            x.Name = "new_textbox" + y;
            x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            x.Height = 25;
            x.Width = 200;
            x.AcceptsReturn = true;
            x.Margin = new Thickness(10, 15, 950, 0);
            spStandard.Children.Add(x);
            y++;
        }
```